# Passing numeric value into a function that uses dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that filters out all rows that contain `NA` and where the adjusted `pvalue` is lower than a certain threshold.

**Code**

```
filter_results <- function(result, pvalue){
    df <- as.data.frame(result)
    df<- df %>%
        filter(!is.na(padj))  %>%
        filter(padj< pvalue)
    return(df)
}

dds_res_filtered_pvalue <- filter_results(dds_res_simple, 0.01)
```

However, this function returns an empty dataframe. Manual input of `pvalue` works as intended:

```
filter_results <- function(result){
    df <- as.data.frame(result)
    df<- df %>%
        filter(!is.na(padj))  %>%
        filter(padj< 0.01) # manual input of pvalue
    return(df)
}

dds_res_filtered_pvalue <- filter_results(dds_res_simple)
```

**Question**

How can I pass numeric values into functions that use `dplyr`?

Comment: You need to use non-standard evaluation in order to apply a dplyr-y function

Comment: @Sotos I don't think so, NSE is needed only when column names are passed to function. Here there are no column names passed.

Comment: @nhaus Can you make this post reproducible by adding data. This function should ideally work.

Comment: Oh..missed that. I rushed into it again. Thought pvalue was a column :)

Comment: here no problems using `library(tidyverse);
filter_results(mtcars %>% 
                 mutate(padj = cyl), 8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the name of your data frame and column names, I guess you are using DESeq2. There is a column called pvalue in your data frame, so you have to use another variable, otherwise it uses the column pvalue in your filter():

```
library(DESeq2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
dds = makeExampleDESeqDataSet(betaSD = 1)
dds = DESeq(dds)
dds_res_simple = results(dds)

colnames(dds_res_simple)
[1] "baseMean"       "log2FoldChange" "lfcSE"          "stat"          
[5] "pvalue"         "padj"
```

Now we modify your function, using "cutoff" instead of pvalue:

```
filter_results <- function(result, cutoff){
    df <- as.data.frame(result)
    df<- df %>%
        filter(!is.na(padj))  %>%
        filter(padj< cutoff)
    return(df)
}
```

And it works:

```
head(filter_results(dds_res_simple,0.05))

 baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue         padj
1  38.01463       1.714453 0.3723547  4.604353 4.137494e-06 6.173404e-05
2  70.35889       1.503615 0.3152131  4.770152 1.840868e-06 2.983475e-05
3  18.94027       1.558557 0.5314113  2.932864 3.358511e-03 1.635751e-02

max(filter_results(dds_res_simple,0.05)$padj)
0.04594662
```